# delete words between specified characters with sed

Tags: command-line, sed

i have a file this format :

Word1 : "Word2" Word3

I want to remove "Word2"

Then file must be like this :

Word1 : Word3

How can i do this with sed?

Note : Word2 is changeable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If file.txt is your file, you can try this from command line:

```
sed -e "s_: \"[a-zA-Z0-9]*\" _: _g" -i file.txt
```

Comment: if i have non-latin characters? :) like "Версия"

Comment: try with: `sed -e "s_: \"[^\"]*\" _: _g" -i file.txt` ;)

Answer (score 1):

If there is no extra stuff in the input_file, just substitute every quoted phrase with empty string:

```
sed 's/"[^"]*"//' input_file
```

Comment: +1, but: strictly speaking, sed is supposed to use Basic Regular Expressions, so \+ should not be valid (but is accepted by many sed implementations).  I think it is probably better to use `*` here, though, since the quoted string may be empty.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line try

```
$ sed -i 's/\"Word2\"//g' /path/to/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If test is your file, try:

```
# cat test | sed -r 's/\".+\"\ //'
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the given input. say, Word2 could be anything, but Word1 and Word3 are fixed. sed/awk oneliner could do the job 4 u:

```
kent$  echo 'Word1 : "Word2" Word3'|sed -r 's/(Word1 :) "[^"]*"( Word3)/\1\2/g' 
Word1 : Word3


kent$  echo 'Word1 : "Word2" Word3'|awk -F"\"" '{print $1,$3}' 
Word1 :   Word3
```